# A movie about a lot of woman clones with mini skirts

Tags: identify-this-movie

There were group of women working in a fastfood restaurant with sexy clothes. They're all look alike. They were probably clones. They were Japanese. They slept in a room that looks like a prison. They were probably slaves. One of them found a mini TV. Another one had sex with a man and watched by the other.

The restaurant has transparent glass with aquatic decoration. It's colorful and hi-tech. It serves fastfood.

Another scene I remember is one of the woman crossing a bridge from one building to another building while being shot by a chopper.

I watched it around 4-5 years ago. It's an American movie.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sounds like the Neo Seoul segment in [Cloud Atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_Atlas_(film)) from 2012.

> Sonmi-451 is a "fabricant", a human cloned for slave labor, living as a server at a fast food restaurant in a dystopian South Korea. She is exposed to ideas of rebellion by another fabricant and friend, Yoona-939. After witnessing Yoona being killed for rebelling, Sonmi is rescued from captivity by Commander Hae-Joo Chang, a rebel.

You can see the scene when they're shot at on a bridge [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NNZwKdBzWM#t=1m17s) and some clips from the clones' lives and the fast food restaurant here (Warning: Slightly Graphic Death Scene):

Comment: Again proved I am slow when it comes to ID

Comment: Oh god, the weird puppet faces. I'm still recovering form Hugo Weaving in drag.

Comment: just watch the trailer and yes, it's the one i am looking for. Thx Walt

Comment: Even after watching this movie again and again, I can't figure out the order of events.

Comment: @Vahn - The book is far far better.